# How to display borderless resizeble grid using python

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm new to coding, my problem is I'm trying to create a program that helps craft in game.
In-game inventory is divided into square cells, I want to create a function
that will help user to select inventory cells he wants for program to use.
For this I need to make a function that will draw a semi-transparent grid that the user can move and resize
after he finish selecting cells the function should return cells coordinates.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQu7c.jpg)

I've tried to google examples but not found anything comprehensible.

Comment: Can you give more information on what tech stack you are using? Sounds like you use pure python or some library like pygame. I think both are not very suitable for what you are asking for.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)